# Use a condition to add items to a dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart, filtering

I have a app with a dropdown menu that shows data from a map, but i want to show only specific items that are not inactive.

```
  Widget _createAssuntoField(BuildContext context, ContatoStore store) {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
      key: Key(ContatoKeys.assuntoInput),
      hint: Text(LocaleKeys.contactSubjectHint).tr(),
      value: store.tipoContato?.id,
      onChanged: (value) => store.tipoContato =
          store.tiposContato.firstWhere((assunto) => assunto.id == value),
      validator: (a) =>
          store.validateAssunto ? null : LocaleKeys.selectRequired.tr(),
      items: store.tiposContato
          .map((a) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                value: a.id,
                child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                    child: Text(a.assunto,
                        maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
```

So the items have a property called "inactive", and i wanted to add to the dropdown only the ones where this propery is false, how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where` on iterables to filter out specific items. In your case you can use this:

```
store.tiposContato.where((e) => !e.inactive)
.map((a) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(...)).toList()
```